# Tag merge / synonym request: [os] → [operating-systems]

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms, tag-merge

Please merge tag [os](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/os) (12 questions) into [operating-systems](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/operating-systems) (65), and make them synonyms.

---

Both tags do not have wiki, only excerpts. For the reference, current excerpts are quoted below

- os

  > <sup>An operating system (OS) is a collection of software that manages computer hardware resources and provides common services for computer programs.</sup>
- operating-systems

  > <sup>An operating system (OS) is a basic software whose rule is to intermediate software requisitions for resources and the hardware available, manage input/output, memory allocation/deallocation, file systems, among other basic tasks a device should do.</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tags were made synonyms:

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Opi8.png]